# How to edit existing pdf file itext7, C#?

Tags: .net-core, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

Before, I edit a field into an existing PDF file as follows:

```
using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(new MemoryStream(templateFileByteArray));
var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, memoryStream, '\0', false);
var pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
pdfFormFields.GenerateAppearances = true;
pdfFormFields.SetField("TextFullName", customer.Name, customer.Name);
pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
pdfReader.Close();
pdfStamper.Close();
```

How can I do it with `iText7`.
in `iText7` I couldn't find `PdfStamper` equivalent.

Comment: Between iText 5.x and iText 7.x there was a complete re-design of the API. Before switching to iText 7, therefore, consider reading some introductions, e.g. the [iText 7: Jump-Start Tutorial for .NET](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net) and [iText 7: Building Blocks](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/itext-7-building-blocks).

Comment: It's too bad that the iText devs haven't published a document helping specifically with migration from iTextSharp. I started with it about 8 years ago. I bought the book, and was able to do a bunch of stuff that I am thankful for, but now in migrating some of that work to iText7, I find there are no official migration notes. It seems like it would be a no-brainer to provide something like that in a day where so many organizations are refactoring to .Net core from older .net apps. I suppose I am late in asking at this point. Just started hitting migration needs this year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rough alternative is the following code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(sourceFile);
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(outFile);
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDocument, false);
form.getField("TextFullName").setValue("Name Value");
form.flattenFields();
pdfDocument.close();
```